# Преобразовать данные из формы тильды

Tags: python, кодировка

Подключил webhook к сайту на тильде, который принимает данные из формы. Готов был уже получить нормальный json, но не тут-то было. Форма присылает данные вида

> Name=dihiqhd&Phone=%2B18525188181&%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F=23-10-1923&%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0=qwdqwd&%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4=dqwd&%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4

Мне нужно преобразовать их средствами python в человеческий словарь. Все с методами decode() encode() для строки я попробовал. Что с этим делать не ясно. Выяснил, что вроде как это windows-1251. Но что мне дальше с этим делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С какого бы перепуга это было win1251? Даже если забить на то, что по идее должно быть utf8, неужели постоянно повторяющиеся `%D0` похожи на однобайтовую кодировку? UPDATE: Странная тула, которая сказала, что это 1251 при том, что смогла преобразовать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет ничего проще:

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qs("Name=dihiqhd&Phone=%2B18525188181&%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F=23-10-1923&%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0=qwdqwd&%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4=dqwd&%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4")
```

```
{'Name': ['dihiqhd'], 'Phone': ['+18525188181'], 'Дата_рождения': ['23-10-1923'], 'Страна': ['qwdqwd'], 'Город': ['dqwd']}
```

Comment: GrAnd Круто! Спасибо!

Comment: @Ivan Если мой ответ вам помог, то можете [отметить его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&text=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0.,%D1%81%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC.).

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием, но оказалось, что не решение. Если я пытаюсь распарсить весь мой код, то питон выдает ошибку
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 26: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Нет, все-таки решение. Отметил